# What are the various Python CMS's and their statuses?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I'm usually a PHP developer that has lots of experience with Drupal CMS & framework. And I realize Drupal is very mature, but I don't know much about the Python scene.

I've heard the following CMSs be mentioned:

- Plone
- Django (framework)

What other CMSs are there, and what do you think are some of the pros and cons? How mature are they? Is it even worth starting to use Python for general web development?

Comment: Good question. I was wondering about this too, as a PHP developer, because Drupal seems to me very clumsy, with a lot of bullshit, and not well set up 'out of the box' at the first sight (note that that's only the first impression, I don't have experience) - especially to be used for content mgmt by other authors with little experience. I'd like to have something more elegant, so I considered plone as it is heavilly used by universities, and quite inexperienced users are able to manage the content. But there's the Python issue ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My vote is for [Django CMS](http://www.django-cms.org/). Django itself is a development framework (but one that gives you a *lot* for free, including an excellent pluggable admin interface). DjangoCMS is an application that you can install into a Django application. I am using DjangoCMS and, as a Django user, I think it's perfect. I'm not what non-Django users would think. It's no Wordpress.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a page which lists the [Python based CMS](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ContentManagementSystems). Zope based Plone is the very popular one and very mature too. Apart from that you, have customized solutions built using Django, like Django-CMS and also there are wiki like MoinMoin Engines. That page gives a lot of options for you.

Comment: I do not see any pros/cons here. You've just given me options, some of which I already confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

Django is not a CMS; it's a web development framework.

That said, Django's roots come from newspaper-oriented CMS-like systems.  Unsurprisingly, that makes Django a very good platform on which to create a CMS.

You can check the state of Django-based CMSs on [Django-packages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/), which tracks the project metrics of many packages.

Comment: Sounds good. I was unsure of whether it was like Drupal (CMS and framework) or just a framework. What about the other questions?

Comment: other questions are other questions; but as for the last, Python (with Django) is _way_ more 'worth it' for web development than PHP

Comment: Hmm really? Care to elaborate (if not you, someone else perhaps?)